# $\binom{n}{k}$ so any $2$ elements differ by $2$ or more

Tags: combinatorics

I have been asked to find the number of all the subsets $B$ of $A$, when $|A|=n$ and $|B|=k$, so that any two elements in $B$ differ by $2$ or more.

I'm sitting here 3 hours on Google and the notebook, and nothing.

Thanks, 
Ran.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: ok thanks for letting me know , i'll make amend :)

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to ways of seating $k$ people in $n$ seats in non-consecutive positions.

For $n=10, k = 3$, e.g. firstly remove $k-1= 2$ seats, $n-k+1 = 8$ seats remain
$\Huge{\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}}$

Choose any $k =3$ of these to seat the people in $\binom{n-k+1}{k} =\binom83 =56$ ways
$\Huge{\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{\color{red}{.}}\boxed{.}\boxed{\color{red}{.}}\boxed{\color{red}{.}}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}}$

Insert back the $2$ seats immediately to the right of each chosen seat except the last
$\Huge{\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{\color{red}{.}}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}\boxed{\color{red}{.}}\boxed{.}\boxed{\color{red}{.}}\boxed{.}\boxed{.}}$

Each such numbered set of occupied seats, here {3,6,8} will be one of the $56$ valid  sets
$\huge{\boxed{1}\boxed{2}\boxed{\color{red}{3}}\boxed{4}\boxed{5}\boxed{\color{red}{6}}\boxed{7}\boxed{\color{red}{8}}\boxed{9}\boxed{10}}$

**Note**

The advantage of the above method is that if we are asked that the elements differ by, say, $3$ or more, it can be extended, else, of course, we can simply choose the $k$ numbers to be in the gaps (incl. ends) of the remaining $n-k$ to get $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$, e,g, for n = 10, k = 3

$\large {\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow\bullet\uparrow}$

Answer (score 1):

I will present two methods, the second of which is a response to a question true blue anil raised about an assertion in Jack D'Aurizio's answer.

**Method 1:**  Suppose we have $k$ green balls and $n - k$ blue balls.  Line up $n - k$ blue balls in a row, leaving gaps between them.  We now have $n - k - 1$ spaces between successive blue balls and the two spaces at the ends of the row for a total of $n - k + 1$ spaces in which to place the green balls.  Select $k$ of these $n - k + 1$ spaces in which to place a green ball.  Now number the balls from left to right.  The numbers on the green balls are the desired subset of $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ that contains no two consecutive elements of $S$.  Since the number of such subsets is equal to the number of ways to select $k$ of the $n - k + 1$ spaces in which to place the green balls, there are 
$$\binom{n - k + 1}{k}$$
subsets of $S$ that do not contain consecutive numbers.

**Method 2:**  Suppose the $j$th ball selected from $S = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ is $a_j$, $1 \leq j \leq k$.  Let 
\begin{align*}
x_1 & = a_1\\
x_j & = a_j - a_{j - 1}, 2 \leq j \leq k\\
x_{k + 1} & = n - a_j
\end{align*}
Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_k + x_{k + 1} = n \tag{1}$$
Since no two elements of the subset of $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ are consecutive, 
$x_j \geq 2$ for $2 \leq j \leq k$, while $x_1 \geq 1$ and $x_{k + 1} \geq 0$.  Let $x_1' = x_1 - 1$; let $x_j' = x_j - 2$ for $2 \leq j \leq k$. Then $x_1'$ is a non-negative integer, as is each $x_j'$.  Substituting $x_1' + 1$ for $x_1$ and $x_j' + 2$ for $x_j$, $2 \leq j \leq k$, in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
x_1' + x_2' + \cdots + x_k' + x_{k + 1} + 2(k - 1) + 1 & = n\\
x_1' + x_2' + \cdots + x_k' + x_{k + 1} + 2k - 1 & = n\\
x_1' + x_2' + \cdots + x_k' + x_{k + 1} & = n - 2k + 1 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to the placement of $k$ addition signs in a row of $n - 2k + 1$ ones.  There are 
$$\binom{n - 2k + 1 + k}{k} = \binom{n - k + 1}{k}$$
such solutions since we must choose which $k$ of the $n - k + 1$ symbols $(n - k + 1$ ones and $k$ addition signs) will be addition signs.

Comment: Great job converting it to a regular stars and bars, though method 1 is obviously simpler !

Comment: I, too have found a way to convert to stars and bars. Instead of the selected elements being $3$ green balls, make them $3$ *objects,* $\boxed{\color{green}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet}\;\boxed{\color{green}\bullet\color{blue}\bullet}\;\boxed{\color{green}\bullet}$. $5$ "bars" are left behind, and so placements can be in $\binom{3+5}{3}$ ways, with the "short" object always last. Of course, there really is no need to use stars and bars.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved through [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).
If we want the number of subsets with $k$ elements of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$
without consecutive elements, we just have to count in how many ways we may place $k$ bars between $n-k$ stars, hence the answer is given by:
$$ \binom{n-k+1}{k}.$$

Comment: A quibble about the wording:  There are $n - k + 1$ places to place the bars since the bars can be placed in the $n - k - 1$ spaces between successive stars or at the two ends of the row.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I am getting a bit confused about the use of  stars and bars here, as the method allows  multiple bars between two stars (and vice  versa), but  here, we can only place one bar between two stars.

Comment: @trueblueanil  The way I read this is that the bars are the selected elements, which is contrary to the way they are usually used.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: My point is that whatever we call the selected elements, the stars and  bars  technique allows them to be lumped together, whereas here we aren't so allowed.

Comment: @trueblueanil  The way I read this is that we have $k$ green balls and $n - k$ blue balls.  The blue balls are laid out in a row, creating $n - k - 1$ gaps between the blue balls and two spaces at the ends of the row for a total of $n - k + 1$ spaces.  We then choose $k$ of those spaces in which to place the $k$ green balls so that no two of the green balls are consecutive.  If we number the $n$ balls from left to right, then the numbers on the green balls are the desired subset of $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: The answer is correct, so is the logic, what I am asking is : can we call it use of "stars and bars"?

Comment: @trueblueanil  I just posted two methods of solution, the second of which makes use of "stars and bars."